# Textview replacing characters not working

Tags: swift, textview, nsattributedstring, nsrange

I am trying to add bold fonts with attributedText in my textview. This font would be applied after some button action, my issue is whenever I add the bold font. It's adding the bold font and repeating the words. In the attached image, the bold font should be added after the word "hello". So it show be **This is bold**

This is what I've tried:

```
 func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if boldFont {
        let boldStyle = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)])
        textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: boldStyle)
    }
    return true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't *know* why your text is repeating. I would *guess* it has to do with you replacing characters in a range while the function also replaces characters in a range (You are replacing a range twice, thus double text).

However, I would not use shouldChangeTextIn method for what you are trying to do. Why not just replace the textView.text on the button click??

```
buttonAction() {
   textView.attributedText = // bolded text
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Whenever I tried your suggestion, all the text in the textview is getting deleted.